# How to select all objects in nested hierarchy by property in react application?

Tags: reactjs, properties, hierarchy

I hope I haven't overlooked a similar question. I think it should be really easy, but I can't find an approach.

I've got an an array filled with objects, the length of the array can differ in every timestamp. Like in the picture: [array with 12 Objects and properties "id", "quality"..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8W74.png)

I am now looking for a simple method to see if the properties of "id" and "quality" are defined by now. 
For example: I can test the type of the first objects property 
using:

```
typeof this.state.net["links"][0]["id"].
```

I am looking for something like this:

```
typeof this.state.net["links"][#]["id"]
```

where "#" selects all values with the property "id" and allows me to see if every property is defined with an string, **without** using a loop. 
Thanks and salute :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lodash for this case is perfect fit, your code to check it looks like

```
import _ from 'lodash'

if (_.every(this.state.net.links, data => typeof data.id === 'string')) {
  // Your logic code
}
```

Actually, lodash uses a loop, but the code is very elegant.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's exactly what i was looking for!